# Rails Couldn't find Part with 'id'=27 [WHERE "parts"."active" = ?] RecordNotFound in PartsController#Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I am trying to create a way for users on my website to delete a comment. I have set up my view like this

```
<li><%= comment.content%> by: <%= comment.user.first_name %> </li>
<% if logged_in? %>
<%=link_to 'delete', part_comment_path(@part, comment), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"}, method: 'DELETE'%>
<%end%>
```

When I click the delete link I get the error "Couldn't find Part with 'id'=27 [WHERE "parts"."active" = ?]" which is coming from the parts controller. Currently my Comments controller is set up like this.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
    @comment = part.comments.create(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to part}
      format.js{}
  end
end

  def destroy
    @part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
    @comment = @part.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
      format.html {redirect_to part}
      format.js{}
  end

private
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

and my Parts controller is set up like this

```
class PartsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show]

  def index
    @parts = Part.all
    @categories = Category.all
    @parts = @parts.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
  end

  def new
    @part = Part.new
  end

  def show
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @part = Part.new(part_params)
      if @part.save
        redirect_to part_path(@part)
  end
end

  def edit
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
      if @part.update_attributes(part_params)
        redirect_to @part
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @part = Part.find(params[:id])
      @part.destroy
        redirect_to parts_path
    end

  private
  def part_params
    params.require(:part).permit(:description, :name, :price, :active, :avatar, :discount, :category_id)
  end
end
```

my routes for comments are nested

```
resources :parts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

My models are arranged so that a Comment belongs_to a Part and a Part has_many Comments. Thanks for the help with this one

Comment: try this redirect_to @part in your destroy method

Comment: can you run `rake routes` and paste the result here? and can you also provide the server log and stack trace for the request?

Comment: try any other comment which you can delete  and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think delete method is not working .Try using this <%=link_to 'delete', part_comment_path(@part, comment), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"}, method: :delete>.And check for any other comment